# How to take a screenshot for frameless transparent qt window?

Tags: qt, winapi, gdi

The Qt Window set window flag and attribute:

```
setWindowFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

Screenshot codes:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
if (!hdc)
{
    LOGE << "Get window dc failed. Code - " << GetLastError();
    return "";
}
SCOPE_GUARD([hwnd, hdc] {
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
});

//get window size
RECT clientRect;
if (hwnd)
{
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &clientRect);
}
else
{
    clientRect.top = 0;
    clientRect.left = 0;
    clientRect.right = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    clientRect.bottom = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
}
LONG rectWidth = clientRect.right - clientRect.left;
LONG rectHeith = clientRect.bottom - clientRect.top;

//create target dc
HDC dcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
if (!dcMemory)
{
    LOGE << "Create compatible dc failed. Code - " << GetLastError();
    return "";
}
SCOPE_GUARD([dcMemory] {
    DeleteObject(dcMemory);
});

HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rectWidth, rectHeith);
if (!hBitmap)
{
    LOGE << "Create compatible bitmap failed. Code - " << GetLastError();
    return "";
}
SCOPE_GUARD([hBitmap] {
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
});

//select and print
{
    HGDIOBJ hOldBitmap = SelectObject(dcMemory, hBitmap);
    SCOPE_GUARD([dcMemory, hOldBitmap] {
        SelectObject(dcMemory, hOldBitmap);
    });

    if (!BitBlt(dcMemory, 0, 0, rectWidth, rectHeith, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY))
    {
        LOGE << "Copy data from DC failed. Code - " << GetLastError();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Finally, I got a black image.

I found [Aeroshot](https://code.google.com/archive/p/aeroshot/) do this. It put target window top and make a black window back. And take screenshot for Display in target window's range.

I don't want to affect the target program. Are there other options?

Comment: How is `hdc` obtained? See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani From GetDC function, I have edited my question.

Comment: The transparent window is probably black, you tell Windows to treat that color as transparent when painting the desktop. So you don't want the `HDC` of the transparent window. Use desktop dc instead `::GetDC(0)`. And `GetWindowRect` to get the coordinates of the transparent window where you want to take snapshot. `BitBlt` that section only. [See example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47697869/4603670)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani That was what [Aeroshot](https://code.google.com/archive/p/aeroshot/) do.

Comment: Take screen shot of desktop. Don't take screen shot of transparent window.