# Getting full screenshot of a specific window, despite the window location

Tags: python, c++, winapi, screenshot, screen-capture

It seems to be pretty problematic to get a **full** screenshot out of **any** window/application.

With the Win32 API I was almost able to archive that, it struggles as it is limited to from which windows it can get image data from - from some windows its impossible (From what I know).

With other methods any window can be screenshotted, but only the parts that are visible on the main screen. A window that is only half in screen results in a screenshot of only the area which is on the screen.

First I've tried it with c++ and the Win32 API according to this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image

I added a window specification and made some adjustments as the example is for the whole screen.

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, windowTitle);
```

It works very well - but not for all windows. This answer seems to give the answer why it doesn't work on all windows.

[C++ WinAPI screenshot of a window in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695843/c-winapi-screenshot-of-a-window-in-the-background)

I gave up on the Win API and tried it with some python libraries. pyautogui and PTL.

They work super easy. However once the window exceeds the screen boundaries, only the part of the window is screenshotted, which lays inside the computer screen.

Comment: Tools like [Greenshot are open source](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot) which might be a good way to find out how this magic happens.

Comment: [New Ways to do Screen Capture](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/). This can be done from C++ and Python, though I wonder why anyone would combine the [tag:python] and [tag:c++] tags. What's with that?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I put both tags in, as I tried to solve the problems in both languages.

Comment: Let's be real: Python is not a programming language. If you care to solve your problem and use a programming language, here's Robert Mikhayelyan's [SimpleRecorder](https://github.com/robmikh/SimpleRecorder) to get you started.

Comment: DPI-aware may help you. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74900930/function-takes-screenshot-of-the-left-top-corner-only

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT No, (lack of) DPI awareness is not the issue. The issue is that if a window is "displayed" outside the desktop area, contents outside cannot be captured using a `BitBlt`. I see a pattern of someone being consistently wrong.